# Why a variable is not defined in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, routes, ejs

I'm developing an application with Node.js and EJS but there is an error. It says "msg_type is not defined". When I'm using handlebars, there is no problem. What is my mistake. Actually, when url goes to /auth/login , the message is displaying but it's not displaying in /login routing.

**my users.js file (controllers)**

```
exports.login = async (req, res,next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).render("login", {
        msg: "Kullanıcı Adınız veya Parolanız Hatalı",
        msg_type: "error",
      },
      next()
      );
    } 
      
    
   await login_db.query(
      "select * from users where email=?",
      [email],
      async (error, result) => {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.length <= 0) {
          return res.status(401).render("login", {
            msg: "E-mailiniz veya Parolanız Hatalı",
            msg_type: "error",
          });
        } else {
          if (!(await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].PASS))) {
            return res.status(401).render("login", {
              msg: "E-mailiniz veya Parolanız Hatalı",
              msg_type: "error",
            });
          } else {
            const id = result[0].ID;
            const token = jwt.sign({ id: id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
              expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
            });
            console.log("The Token is " + token);
            const cookieOptions = {
              expires: new Date(
                Date.now() +
                  process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
              ),
              httpOnly: true,
            };
            res.cookie("joes", token, cookieOptions);
            res.status(200).redirect("/anasayfa");
          }
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**my auth.js file**

```
const express = require("express");
const userController = require("../controllers/users");
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/login", userController.login);
```

**my login.ejs file**

```
<% if (true) { %>
        
        <p class="<%= msg_type %>"><%= msg %> </p>

       <% } %>



      <form action="/auth/login" method="post">
        <div class="data">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="data">
          <label for="password">Şifre</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="forgot-pass">
          <a href="#">Şifrenizi mi unuttunuz?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
          <button type="submit">Giriş Yap</button>
        </div>
        <div class="signup-link">
          Kayıtlı değil misin?<a href="/register"> Şimdi Kayıt Ol!</a>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**my app.js file**

```
app.use("/", require("./routes/pages"));
 app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"))
```

;

**my pages.js file**

```
router.get(["/", "/login"], (req, res) => {
  //res.send("<h1>Hello Tutor Joes Salem</h1>");
  res.render("login");
});
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

The variable should be exported from the original file(users.js) and also should be imported in login.ejs, so you can use it without problems, this is how things work in Javascript.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).